# Adding object into grid

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add a class that contains graphics into a class of grid?
Currently I have error on the *CreateGraphics*.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Othello
{
class Board : Grid
{
    public Grid grid = new Grid();
    ColumnDefinition col;
    RowDefinition row;

    int boxesAmount = 8;
    int boxSize = 100;
    int i = 0;

    public Board()
    {
        grid.Width = boxSize * boxesAmount;
        grid.Height = boxSize * boxesAmount;
        grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        grid.ShowGridLines = true;
        grid.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

        for (i = 0; i < boxesAmount; i++)
        {
            // Create Columns
            col = new ColumnDefinition();
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);

            // Create Rows
            row = new RowDefinition();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(grid));
        this.Children.Add(grid);

        Chess chess = new Chess();
        grid.Children.Add(chess);
        Grid.SetColumn(chess, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(chess, 0);
    }
}
}
```

2nd Class that contains the graphics

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Othello
{

    class Chess : UserControl
    {
        Graphics g;

        public Chess()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("load chess");

            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 30, 30, 50, 50);
            this.AddChild(g);
        }
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
error CS1061: 'Othello.Chess' does not contain a definition for 'CreateGraphics' and no extension method 'CreateGraphics' accepting a first argument of type 'Othello.Chess' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Just saying there's an error doesn't help at all. **Which error** do you get? i.e. Type of exception and StackTrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `UserControl` or its base classes just doesn't contain the method, exactly as the compiler error tells you. You can also notice things like that when the method does *not* appear in Intellisense when writing Code. You probably immediately got a red squiggly line when typing that.

`CreateGraphics` is Windows Forms. But you are using WPF. Those two are different UI Frameworks with different classes (which have different methods). Did you accidently create a WPF Custom Control Library but wanted to create a Windows Forms Controls Library?

Try something like this in the XAML file for your control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Margin="30"></Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Alternatively, you could override [`OnRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender.aspx) to provide custom painting.